# Full-Text Searching in CRM 2011

Tags: full-text-search, dynamics-crm-2011

I was doing some research around different areas of Dynamics CRM 2011 and i came across the Articles entity. Looking around some I noticed the search tab in the ribbon where you can configure loads of different searches for the articles, including Full-Text Searching. This confused me a little as i was always told that we couldn't use this in CRM 2011 but seeing this makes me wonder.

So is it possible to actually use this in CRM 2011, or is it just a special feature for this one entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full-Text Searching only applies to Knowledge Base entities.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309378.aspx

Comment: Ah right, i guess theres no way to apply this to other ones then?

Comment: No, but what is your overall goal?

Comment: I was looking into the duplication checks of CRM 2011, and thought that the way that it only really offered exact matching was a bit limited, so when i saw that full-text searching could be applied to these entities, i was hoping that there'd be some way to adapt it to make the duplication checks better

Comment: We use www.trilliumsoftware.com with far better success than the exact match.  Trillium matches on nicknames really well (e.g. Bob/Bobby/Rob/Robby for Robert).  It also picks up misspellings fairly well.